# How to generate ICMPv6 "packet-too-big" using ip6tables

Tags: linux, ipv6, iptables

Using ip6tables following ICMP error codes can be generated (as per the man page):

```
--reject-with type
              The  type  given  can   be   icmp6-no-route,   no-route,   icmp6-adm-prohibited,   adm-prohibited, icmp6-addr-unreachable,  addr-unreach,  icmp6-port-unreachable  or  port-unreach  which return the appropriate ICMPv6 error message (port-unreach is the default).
```

Example:

```
[root@outside-pc ~]# ip6tables -A INPUT -s 2001::/64 -p ICMPv6  -j REJECT --icmpv6-type destination-unreachable
[root@outside-pc ~]# ip6tables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 2001::/64 -p ipv6-icmp -m icmp6 --icmpv6-type 1 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable
```

***Is it possible to generate other error codes like "packet-too-big" (type 2, code 0) using ip6tables ?***

Comment: Tried using following, but with no luck -
 [root@outside-pc ~]# ip6tables -A INPUT -p icmpv6 -j REJECT --icmpv6-type 2/0
 [root@outside-pc ~]# ip6tables -S
 -P INPUT ACCEPT
 -P FORWARD ACCEPT
 -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp -m icmp6 --icmpv6-type 2/0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to your question appears to be "no" unfortunately. You can see the kernel code with implements the `REJECT` target [here](https://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=net/ipv6/netfilter/ip6t_REJECT.c;h=fd4fb34c51c7f5b9bd62294de2abb6da943ee494;hb=HEAD#l182) and it looks like this:

```
static unsigned int
reject_tg6(struct sk_buff *skb, const struct xt_action_param *par)
{
    const struct ip6t_reject_info *reject = par->targinfo;
    struct net *net = dev_net((par->in != NULL) ? par->in : par->out);

    pr_debug("%s: medium point\n", __func__);
    switch (reject->with) {
    case IP6T_ICMP6_NO_ROUTE:
        send_unreach(net, skb, ICMPV6_NOROUTE, par->hooknum);
        break;
    case IP6T_ICMP6_ADM_PROHIBITED:
        send_unreach(net, skb, ICMPV6_ADM_PROHIBITED, par->hooknum);
        break;
    case IP6T_ICMP6_NOT_NEIGHBOUR:
        send_unreach(net, skb, ICMPV6_NOT_NEIGHBOUR, par->hooknum);
        break;
    case IP6T_ICMP6_ADDR_UNREACH:
        send_unreach(net, skb, ICMPV6_ADDR_UNREACH, par->hooknum);
        break;
    case IP6T_ICMP6_PORT_UNREACH:
        send_unreach(net, skb, ICMPV6_PORT_UNREACH, par->hooknum);
        break;
    case IP6T_ICMP6_ECHOREPLY:
        /* Do nothing */
        break;
    case IP6T_TCP_RESET:
        send_reset(net, skb);
        break;
    default:
        net_info_ratelimited("case %u not handled yet\n", reject->with);
        break;
    }

    return NF_DROP;
}
```

As you can see it only supports the types that you have already discovered.